android studio "jellyfish" emulator is showing but not working
I've installed new version - jellyfish But the emulator is working and unable to run stuck at booting for several hours, more than 2 hours.
Getting error "No Target Device found."
Android Studio Version:
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024


Have you tried re-creating the emulator and also re-opening Android Studio?

yes, same error

My issue resolve when I select this option in Settings->Debugger -> Use existing manually managed server  -> Existing ADB server port:

